# How to compute $ \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\int_w^{w+tv}f(y)dy}{t} $?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, limits

$w,v\in R$ and $f\in C^\infty(R)$ . How to compute 
$$
\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\int_w^{w+tv}f(y)dy}{t}
$$

I feel it should be $vf(w)$, but I don't know how to prove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try l'Hopital's rule:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\int_w^{w+tv}f(y)dy}{t} &= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\frac{d}{\,dt}\int_w^{w+tv}f(y)\,dy}{\frac{d}{\,dt}t} \\
&=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{vf(w+tv) }{1} = vf(w)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

That's the chain rule. Define $F\colon \def\R{\mathbf R}\R \to \R$ by 
$$ F(x) = \int_w^x f(y)\, dy $$
Then $F'(x) = f(x)$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus. Now let $G(t) = F(w+tv)$. Then, on one side 
$$ G'(0)= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{G(t)- G(0)}t = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{F(w+tv)}{t}
  = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\int_w^{w+tv} f(y)\, dy}t
$$ 
on the other side, by the chain rule
$$ G'(t) = F'(w+tv)\cdot v = f(w+tv) \cdot v $$
Hence 
$$  \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\int_w^{w+tv} f(y)\, dy}t = G'(0) = f(w)v $$